# How to setup background color instead of color?

Tags: angularjs

```
<tr dir-paginate="test in data" ng-style="calculateStyle(test)">
<td>{{test.FirstName}}</td>
<td>{{test.LastName}}</td>
<td>{{test.Status}}</td>
</tr>

$scope.calculateStyle = function(test) {
    var style = {}
    if (test.Status == 'Cleared')
        style.color = 'green';
    return style;
}
```

How to setup background color instead of color. I used `backgroundColor`, but it is not working.

Comment: How you are using this `calculateStyle` in UI ?

Comment: `backgroundColor` will [work](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/ADukg/15826/), check your condition, may be that not working

Comment: im using funcrion in ng repeat - table

Comment: `if (test.Status == 'Cleared')` check the value

Comment: condition is ok. i used style.color it is working. when i use backgroundColor it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Use `style['background-color']= 'green'`

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/364i3Wm4Gu3aGIFVKAl3?p=preview)

[Src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

Comment: See this : https://plnkr.co/edit/364i3Wm4Gu3aGIFVKAl3?p=preview There's probably issue in your code. `'background-color'` and `backgroundColor` both are working.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `style['background']:'green'` or `style.background:'green'`